# Rails how to use infinite scroll with datagrid and datatable?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable, datagrid, infinite-scroll

## I have a problem while using infinite scroll with datagrid.

I want to do infinite scroll when scrolling to the bottom of the table and fetch the next page data.
I'm using jquery infinite scroll + kaminari gem, dataTable and Datagrid.

- if i'm scrolling to the bottom of the table, its fetch new page data correctly.
- but when i filterd some columns (using datagrid), its fetch the next page data and looping the same data again and again when i'm scrolling to the bottom.
- its working as normal if i don't filtered with datagrid.

## gem & js library

```
gem 'datagrid'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'
gem 'kaminari'

https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll
```

## controller

```
respond_to do |f|
  f.html do
    @client_grid.scope { |scope| scope.accessible_by(current_ability).page(params[:page]).per(20) }
  end
  f.js do
    @client_grid.scope { |scope| scope.accessible_by(current_ability).page(params[:page]).per(20) }
  end
end
```

## view

```
  .col-xs-12      
    .ibox-content
      .clients-table
        %table.table.table-bordered.table-striped.table-hover.clients
          %thead
            = datagrid_header(@client_grid)
          %tbody.page
            = render 'client_rows'

    .ibox-footer.text-center.hidden
      = paginate @client_grid.assets
```

## Coffee

```
$("table.clients .page").infinitescroll
  navSelector: "ul.pagination" # selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
  nextSelector: "ul.pagination a[rel=next]" # selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
  itemSelector: "table.clients tbody tr" # selector for all items you'll retrieve
  loading: {
    img: 'http://i.imgur.com/qkKy8.gif'
    msgText: '<em>Loading clients...</em>'
  }
  donetext: "<em>You've reached the end.</em>"
  binder: $('.clients-table .dataTables_scrollBody')
```

Comment: did you fix it ?:)